# pcp_attach_node not working in pgpool 2

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I've been working on pgpool2 setup with 2 DB node and I need to attach on the node, which os currently down. when I run

`postgres@pg-pool:~$ pcp_attach_node -p 9898 -n 1 -U postgres`

I get following error.

> pcp_attach_node -p 9898 -n 1 -U postgres pcp_attach_node: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libpcp.so.1: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

I am using:

```
- pgpool-II-4.0.1
- ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- postgresql 10
```

**I have installed:**

```
postgresql-contrib 
gcc 
make 
libpq-dev
```

**pgpool installation:**

```
./configure
make
make install
```

**Contents of /usr/local/lib**

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     959 Mar 18 07:55 libpcp.la*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Mar 18 07:55 libpcp.so -> libpcp.so.1.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Mar 18 07:55 libpcp.so.1 -> libpcp.so.1.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  244296 Mar 18 07:55 libpcp.so.1.0.0*
```

Your help would be great

Comment: Looks like a dynamic loader configuration issue. What is the value of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? Try to add /usr/local/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the environment that starts pgpool. See details in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354295/what-is-the-default-value-of-ld-library-path.

Comment: @pifor you are correct. your suggestion is working.

Answer (score 0):

As @pifor mentioned the issues was $LD_LIBRARY_PATH . Following code has fixed my issue.

Thank you @pifor

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```